# Redrawing WMS layer on OpenLayers without flickering from GeoServer?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms

I have a WMSlayer that is updated every 10sec with new data from SQL.
Whenever I redraw the layer using redraw(true) , the map screen flickers.

Is there a way to do it without flickering ?

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding the layer on top, then removing it below.

What I mean is, you might be able to alternate between two layers that contain the same source. Add one, then remove the other. Then do it the other way. Only tiles that change will appear different, but it will need to reload data every 10 sec.

Comment: This seems "heavy" on the client. The weird thing is that Geoserver running on Jetty does flicker , but when I moved to tomcat 7 (on windows) it doesn't.... (but crush on other occasion)

Comment: I can't help then. Perhaps the GeoServer forums might help?

Answer (score -1):

in source of your layer you need to add param

```
transition: 0
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend thinking of a minimum length post (question or answer) here as being "about a paragraph" but most are at least a couple of paragraphs.